# Python: import graphutil module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am modifying an old python code which imports graphutil module. However I am unable to find the source-package for the module and install it on ubuntu. Any help in this direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it [this `GraphUtil` module](http://pythonhosted.org/altgraph/graphutil.html)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters- the code contains the line: import graphutil

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is it, but there was a [file](https://code.google.com/p/pywafo/source/browse/trunk/pywafo/src/wafo/graphutil.py?spec=svn64&r=64) in pywafo that may have been lifted for your project. This is the best I can find.